# event falls on start date of one event and end date of another

Tags: sql

I have two sql tables

```
declare @events table (id int, [event date] date)
```

and

```
declare @ranges table (id int, [start date] date, [end date] date)
```

I'm trying to match an event to a range with the following query

```
select 
    e.id as eid, r.id as rid
from 
    @events as e
inner join 
    @ranges as r on (e.[event date] between r.[start date] and r.[end date]);
```

The problem I'm having is that if an event date is on end date of one event and start date of another event, it would show up twice in the query result. The event should match to only one event. for example

```
insert into @events values(1, '2014-01-02'); --date falls on end date on one event and start date of another event

insert into @ranges values(2, '2014-01-01','2014-01-02'),(3,'2014-01-02','2014-01-04');`
```

I get the following result

```
eid  | rid
1        2 
1        3
```

How can make it match to just one range and ignore the other (preferably match the earlier date range)?

Comment: A cheap fix would be Select distinct * from .......

Comment: @happs That still returns the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @GPicazos' answer doesn't cover the situation where you can have earlier `start_date` in your `ranges` table added later (with bigger `ranges.id`), because `ranges.id` doesn't need to determine your values stored inside `date` columns I'm posting this answer.

I will only show you how to deal with those rows that have more than 1 match in `ranges` table. This is basically what you've asked. I'm leaving latter case (with only 1 match) as an exercise for you, since it doesn't involve complicated queries.

We're starting with your query that is put inside `cte_events`.

Then, the next CTE `events_multiple_matches` outputs only those `event_id's` that have multiple matches.

Next step - `events_first_date_range` takes minimum `start_date` from `ranges` table. Here I assumed, that you don't have more than 1 row inside `ranges` table with the same `start_date`.

Since we have a `start_date` from `ranges` table from the previous step we can connect to the `ranges` table once again to retrieve `ranges_id` and (if needed) additional columns - `start_date` and `end_date`.

Hope this helps. Below the code I've attached an SQL fiddle with your example.

```
WITH cte_events AS (
SELECT
  e.id AS event_id,
  e.event_date
FROM
  events e
  INNER JOIN ranges r ON
    e.event_date BETWEEN r.start_date AND r.end_date
)
, events_multiple_matches AS (
SELECT
  event_id
FROM
  cte_events
GROUP BY event_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
, events_first_date_range AS (
SELECT
  e.event_id,
  MIN(r.start_date) AS min_start_date
FROM
  cte_events e
  INNER JOIN events_multiple_matches em ON e.event_id = em.event_id
  INNER JOIN ranges r ON e.event_date BETWEEN r.start_date AND r.end_date
GROUP BY
  e.event_id
)
SELECT
  e.event_id,
  r.id AS ranges_id,
  r.start_date,
  r.end_date
FROM
  events_first_date_range e
  INNER JOIN ranges r ON e.min_start_date = r.start_date
```

Here's an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c686/5) to show you how it works.

Comment: That answers the question. Thanks @considerMe

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date ranges are entered in increasing order, the following query should work. If not, then there isn't a guarantee that you will get the one that matches on start date instead of end date.

```
select orig.eid, min(orig.rid)
from (
    select e.id as eid, r.id as rid
    from  @events as e
        inner join @ranges as r
            on (e.[event date] between r.[start date] and r.[end date])
) as orig
group by orig.eid
```